# java.net.ConnectException after changing hostname

Tags: hadoop

I had set up hadoop in standalone mode, with the default hostname "raspberrypi".

Things seemed to be working.

I then changed the hostname to `hnode1` by doing:

```
echo "hnode1" | sudo tee /etc/hostname
```

and in `/etc/hosts` I changed

```
127.0.0.1 raspberrypi
```

to

```
127.0.0.1 hnode1
```

The only other change I made was in core-site.xml :

```
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
```

was changed to

```
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://hnode1:9000</value>
  </property>
```

However, after restarting services when attempting to copy from the local file system to hdfs I get this error:

```
Call From hnode1/127.0.1.1 to hnode1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;
```

I have also tried rebooting and I have verified that I can ssh to `hnode1`

Answer (score 1):

Your hosts file should look like this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Remove lines with `127.0.1.1` and hard-coded references to the hostname

Your DNS server should know how to resolve `hnode1`, not have the Pi point back at itself, because then HDFS clients will get looped back to the Pi when communicating to the Namenode.

Your SSH connection proves DNS seems to be working.

And rename the deprecated property `fs.default.name` to its new name `fs.defaultFS`

Comment: Thanks, but now I get `Call From java.net.UnknownHostException: hnode1: hnode1: unknown error to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Comment: I have managed to fix it, by stopping the services, doing `rm -Rf /tmp/*`, `hdfs namenode -format` and then restarting the services. However I don't understand why this is necessary, and obviously the data was lost (not a big deal in this case but....)

Comment: I don't think the namenode needs formatting, but then again, I've never changed the HDFS address after starting a cluster...

Comment: It's very strange. If I don't reformat then the error persists.

Comment: Are you running the hdfs commands from a remote machine or from the ssh session?

Comment: From ssh. the Pi is plugged into my router and I am working from a windows laptop